# What is this colourful insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this colourful  insect in our garden. It measures about 1.5cm. I am from Kuching, Sarawak, Malaysiai

[image]

Comment: Not that colourful IMO! What do you think it could be? Look like some hymenoptera with its apocrita to me

Comment: The short orange antennae and the round eyes are those of a Diptera, although I can't tell the family

Comment: Check on from yr response i.e. Diptera order, I think it is from Family:Micropezidae.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a stilt-legged fly from the family Micropezidae.
https://www.singaporegeographic.com/insects/insect/stilt-legged-fly-micropezidae

Perhaps, more specifically:  *Mimegralla albimana*